# How to test if player is flying

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm confused on the new 1.14 scoreboard update. If a player is flying with the Elytra is it possible to make a firework appear in their offhand.

Comment: What "1.14 scoreboard update"? 1.14 didn't change **anything** related to scoreboards. Also, what have you tried yourself? Please read the [tour] page, it tells you for example that we expect askers to first try to do things themselves and only if they can't, ask here about the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "scoreboard update", as nothing changed in 1.14 in terms of scoreboards. You can check everything that was added in 1.14 [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.14)

The [command syntax](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.13#Command_format_2) was changed in 1.13 if this is what you mean.

It terms of what you would like to do, it's pretty simple. All you have to do is execute for players that are gliding with an elyra, which is stored in a player's [NBT data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags)

Afterward, run your `replaceitem` command in the execute.  No scoreboards are needed for this.

`/execute as @a[nbt={FallFlying:1b}] run replaceitem entity @s weapon.offhand minecraft:firework_rocket <count>` This would generally go into an `always active`, `repeating` command block.